# MongoDB WriteConcern Java Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka

I have a simple mongo application that happens to be async (using Akka).
I send a message to an actor, which in turn write 3 records to a database.
I'm using WriteConcern.SAFE because I want to be sure the write happened (also tried WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE).

I pause for a second to let the writes happen then do a read--and get nothing.

So my write code might be:

```
collection.save( myObj, WriteConcern.SAFE )
println("--1--")
collection.save( myObj, WriteConcern.SAFE )
println("--2--")
collection.save( myObj, WriteConcern.SAFE )
println("--3--")
```

then in my test code (running outside the actor--in another thread) I print out the # of records I find:

```
println( collection.findAll(...) )
```

My output looks like this:

```
--1--
--2--
--3--
(pauses)
0
```

Indeed if I look in the database I see no records.  **Sometimes I actually do see data there** and the test works.  Async code can be tricky and it's possible the test code is being hit before the writes happen, so I also tried printing out timestamps to ensure these are being executed in the order presented--they are.  The data should be there.  Sample output below w/timestamps:

```
Saved: brand_1 / dev  1375486024040
Saved: brand_1 / dev2 1375486024156
Saved: brand_1 / dev3 1375486024261
                      1375486026593 0 found
```

So the 3 saves clearly happened (and should have written) a full 2 seconds before the read was attempted.

I understand for more liberal WriteConcerns you could get this behavior, but I thought the two safest ones would assure me the write actually happened before proceeding.

Comment: Timestamp outputs from your app only proves that the operations were executed in order, but it doesn't prove that when the count query was executed, MongoDB should have completed the inserts. Also note that a pause isn't a reliable way to handle async calls. You really need callbacks and form of a control flow. However a 2second wait is ample of time to perform 3 inserts as inserts on typical size documents should happen in a few ms or less. Which Java driver are you using? Are you using the community async driver, or the MongoDB native driver?

Comment: I'm using java driver 2.11.2 via casbah.  The pause is needed because the writes happen deep inside async logic path while the read is part of a test suite (scalatest).  Production code doesn't rely on pauses...the test just needs to wait enough time to reasonably ensure everything happened.  My head-scratcher is that I thought the SAFE or FSYNC_SAFE WriteConcern was supposed to ensure the write occured before returning control meaning in theory the write should be done when the timestamp is printed.  These results make me doubt my understanding of these WriteConcerns.

Comment: Write concern Safe ensures writes return error info to the client, which could be related to networking, constraints violation like dupe keys and other errors (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/). This is opposed to "fire-and-forget" unacknowledged writes. Fsync means that MongoDB will respond back with error info only after your write has been flushed into the data files. Normally MongoDB just writes into virtual memory (mem map files), and under the typical code path, flushes the changes into the data files and/or journal asynchronously.

Comment: The best first step is to see whether MongoDB received the save requests. Set the profiler level to 2 (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/). Mongosniff may also help to see what is being sent over to MongoDB (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongosniff/)

Comment: I'll try the sniffer, but I did capture the result of the insert.  I ran it 2 times.  Both times I got an ObjectId back for the inserted document, however when I looked at the database using the command line I can only see one of the 2 inserts.  The other simply isn't there.  So using WriteConcern.SAFE I'm getting insert returns that show successful but intermittently I'm not seeing records written to disk.

Comment: A though...  At the time these writes happen there are several (6-10) writes happening simultaneously on the same collection.  Is there possibly some default config in Mongo's server that times out within a short time (perhaps a few seconds)?  If that's true the server may have already responded with "success" (objectId) but ultimately fails as the block timeout kicks in.  Possible?

Comment: The default ObjectIds that MongoDB generates are generated on the client side by the driver. MongoDB creates them based on a combo of timestamp, machine ID, and process ID to ensure universal uniqueness. With that said, the objectId isn't a good indicator that MongoDB actually received the write commands. The sniffer would be a good start to ensure that the commands were actually issued. With WC=SAFE, a successfully submitted command should return an error in the case of a network error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtle but simple problem.  I was using a def to create my connection... which I then proceeded to call twice as if it was a val.  So I actually had 2 different writers so that explained the sometimes-difference in my results.  Refactored to a val and all was predictable.  Agonizing to identify, easy to understand/fix.